# Run Win7 disk partition image with Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

So, i cat'ed my windows partition into a file (plain `cat /dev/sdx > win7.bin`).
`mount -o loop -t ntfs` mounts the image correctly and lets me read/write everything.

Now the question is: could i run this OS image straight within Virtualbox? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

[Convert physical disk to vm](https://https:/https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm/)

> VirtualBox can mount entire physical hard disks as well as only
> selected partitions of a drive. In today’s tutorial, we will only
> discuss mounting entire VirtualBox physical hard disks.
>
> VirtualBox Raw Hard Disk Access This method is called VirtualBox “raw
> hard disk access.” This allows you to mount or boot a secondary hard
> drive or external USB, for example. We’ll show how to do this when
> running VirtualBox on a Windows, Linux or Mac OS X host machine.
>
> You’ll first want to create a virtual machine within the VirtualBox
> GUI. Choose all options like normal, but when asked about the virtual
> hard drive, select Do not add a virtual hard drive.
>
> Next, you’ll need to find the path and drive number of the physical
> drive you’d like to mount:
>
> In Windows, open Disk Management. You’ll see the associated drive
> numbers on the left and will identify them later as PhysicalDrive0,
> PhysicalDrive1, etc.
>
> In Linux, run the following command: sudo fdisk -l. You’ll see a
> listing of the partitions. Make note of the desired drive in the
> format of dev/sda0, dev/sda1, etc.
>
> In Max OS X, use the following command: diskutil list. You’ll see a
> listing of the partitions. Make note of the desired drive in the
> format of /dev/disk0, /dev/disk1, etc.
>
> Now open the CLI of your OS. If you’re using Windows as the host OS
> you will also need to go to the root directory of VirtualBox using the
> following command: cd C:Program FilesOracleVirtualBox
>
> Now you can run the command to create the virtual hard drive file that
> points to your desired physical drive. For each of the following
> examples ensure that you input the desired names between the arrows
> and replace the number or pound sign with your desired drive number.
>
> For Windows:
>
> VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename
> "C:Users<user_name>VirtualBox VMs<VM_folder_name><file_name>.vmdk"
> -rawdisk .PhysicalDrive#

It may be easier just to convert the machine to a virtual machine and use the virtual machine. That will last longer as well. Your physical disk will eventually die.  Virtual machines can last almost forever. Some of mine are a couple of decades old and continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, i managed to convert the raw image into  a vmdk! However, that ppartition was not the one with a bootloader on. Any suggestion for how to boot it?

Comment: I am not entirely certain . You might be able to start with a Windows 7 repair USB.  See if you can start with that. I am not sure .

Comment: I tried with the installation media disc iso -> repair bootloader, but it doesn't even find the OS.. Maybe adding a second disc, and installing a grub in there or something?